# C# - Add Second JSON string to existing class

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a pair of classes that look something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

In order to populate the parent class, I make an API call and deserialize the returned JSON which looks like this:

JSON

```
{
 “parent”:{
   “id”:”123”,
   “name”:”parent name”,
   “child”:{
       “id”:”456″
   },
 }
}
```

C#

```
var parent = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Parent>>(jsonString);
```

I then use the `id` of the `child` to make another API call which returns more details about the `child` that I need to use to populate the `parent`:

```
{
 “child”:{
   “id”:”456”,
   “name”:”child name”
 }
}
```

How can I populate the rest of the `Parent` class with the data from the `child` JSON string?

Comment: It's not very clear whether you want to populate in C# or populate the embedded `child` object of the parent json?

Comment: Doesn't your second API call give you all the relevant information concerning child?

Comment: @danielcooperxyz What I would like is for the C# object (Parent class) to be populated with the combined data from both JSON strings

Comment: @KevinAvignon Yes, the second API call gives me all the relevant info, I just need to somehow associate it with the parent

Comment: I'd take a look at this post and get a close look at the JSON.net API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781996/linq-query-jobject

Comment: Does parent.children = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Child>>(newJsonStringAfterApiCall); work?

Comment: So why not just find given child by id in `Parent.children` list and replace with full info?

Comment: @Evk Because the child object does not contain everything I need relating to the parent

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. In your example "partial" detail of child has only child id. So after first call, Parent.children list is populated but with partial info. Then you make another call and replace partial info with full, why not?

Comment: @Evk That's what I'm asking, how do I replace the partial info with the full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all you need is just make request for every partial child from `Parent.children` and then replace whole collection with full children information:

```
var parents = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Parent>>(jsonString);
foreach (var parent in parents) {
    var fullChildren = new List<Child>();
    foreach (var partialChild in parent.children) {
        var fullChild = GetChildJsonById(partialChild.id);
        fullChildren.Add(fullChild);
    }
    // just replace whole stuff
    parent.children = fullChildren;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I am fairly certain you can do something like:

```
var child = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Child>(jsonString);
```

There shouldn't be more to it than that, assuming all you want is to update your child class.

This seems inefficient though, I don't know why the full child object isn't given from the first api call.

Comment: That works, but now I have two variables/objects with the data split. I would like `var parent` from my example above to contain all the info in the nested `child` As far as the full child object isn't given in the first call, that would be a question for the third party developer

Comment: Since you already have an instance of "parent", you can use "parent.children" along with @BrockReed code above to deserialize directly into the "children" property, right?

Comment: Then it seems the best you could do is use the Parent.children.id in your second call and that second call will populate the Child class properly.. that would give you the full 2 classes like you are looking for. Was that not everything you wanted?